# How to rename a domain computer in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, powershell-5.0, computer-name

I've been trying to rename a domain computer with the following script:

```
$username = "domain\username"
$password = "password"
$ip = ((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
$hostname = (nslookup $ip)[3]
$hostname = $hostname.replace(" ", "")
$hostname = $hostname.split(":")[1]
$hostname = $hostname.split(".")[0].ToLower()
Rename-Computer -NewName $hostname -DomainCredential $username  -Restart -Force
```

It does everything I desire apart from inputting the password which at this point is a manual process. Can someone advise me on how to get it to input from `$password` into the prompt box so that I can completely automate the process?

Alternatively, if there's a better way to do it in Powershell, I'm open to going another direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$Username = "DomainUserName"
$Password = "PlainPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username ,$Password)


Rename-Computer -NewName $newComputerName -ComputerName $OldName -Restart -DomainCredential $Creds
```

Comment: I made a few minor changes to bring this inline with my original above script but it worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The only thing that needs to be added (since I'm using a deployment environment to use this script) is adding the line at the beginning: 


Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass.

This will allow it to Bypass the Execution Policy that blocks non-signed powershell scripts/commands if it's locked down through GPOs.